# Android Firebase Authentication recreates activity forever

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-authentication

I´m using Firebase to register my users and require authentication to go to the home screen implementing the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method and an `Intent`.

The authentication is working fine, it successfully login my users, **BUT** the problem is that when the authentication is successful and the `HomeActivity` starts, the Activity **keeps on recreating infinitely** and the screen stays black.

I´ve tried many ways of doing the `Intent` to move from the `MainActivity` to the `HomeActivity` after the login but that infinite loop keeps happening.
The weird thing is, **if you close the app while the screen is black, "Force Stop" and then open the app again, the app goes to the `HomeActivity` directly without a problem.** The `HomeActivity` contains a `FrameLayout` with a `Fragment`.

I do have the correct Gradle implementation for Firebase.

This is how the `MainActivity.java`'s `OnStart()` and `attemptLogin()` look like:

```
    private void attemptLogin() {
        String email = Objects.requireNonNull(mEditTextUsername.getText()).toString().trim();
        String password = Objects.requireNonNull(mEditTextPassword.getText()).toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            mInputLayoutUsername.setError(getString(R.string.error_emptySpace));
            mInputLayoutPassword.setError(getString(R.string.error_emptySpace));
            return;
        }
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mEnterButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

//        Use Auth to sign in with email & password
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
            finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (mUser != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Going home because mUser is not null");
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
```

In the Logcat this lines of code repeat forever (Some of them I use them as debug logs, like tha one of the Home has been created and the Fragment)

```
D/HomeActivity: onCreate: Home has been created
D/HomeActivity: onCreate: Fragment placed correctly
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 25049213
V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 9
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 25049222
V/FA: onActivityCreated
```

**Inside of the `HomeActivity` I don't use a `recreate()` at all.**

**Thanks for your answers. I hope you can help me make that the app goes directly from the `MainActivity` into the `HomeActivity` without it recreating forever**

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, it will automatically be redirected to HomeActivity after successful login. If already login then on App Start HomeActivity will start.

```
private void signIn(String mail, String password) {


    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(mail,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {


            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    updateUI();    
            }
            else {
                showMessage(task.getException().getMessage());


            }


        }
    });



}

private void updateUI() {

    startActivity(HomeActivity);
    finish();

}

private void showMessage(String text) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(user != null) {
        //user is already connected  so we need to redirect him to home page
        updateUI();

    }



}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried implementing it but unfortunately I keep getting the same problem: The screen stays black after loging in.

Comment: try checking your .xml file of home activity, maybe there is some layout problem in it.